# Avoid insertion in mongoDB Without Data

Tags: mongodb

How can i avoid the insertion in mongoDB if there is no data. Because every time i use insert command it is creating _id without data.
Example : db.collection_name.insert({})
is creating _id in document. How to avoid it.

Comment: why you are calling ".insert({})"? MongoDB is schema less, then calling "insert" with an empty object will create a new Document with _id (default indexed field). So is exactly what MongoDB is able to do :-)

Comment: Actually i am submitting the form. I have done front-end javascript validation but in case javascript is disable i want to check it on server side as well. I am using express with monk in nodeJs.

Comment: More clear now. I will write a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use mongoose ORM and can define validators like:

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Which will generate an error message that looks like:

name:

```
  { message: 'Validator "required" failed for path name',
     name: 'ValidatorError',
     path: 'name',
     type: 'required' } }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i am using monk. Is there a way to avoid insertion if the req.body is empty. It should not insert the value.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 3.2 has schema validation integrated.
So you can just check if "name" property exists, if not then the validation fail and then the Document will be not inserted at all.

https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/core/document-validation/

```
db.createCollection( "contacts",
   { validator: { $or:
      [
         { phone: { $type: "string" } },
         { email: { $regex: /@mongodb\.com$/ } },
         { status: { $in: [ "Unknown", "Incomplete" ] } }
      ]
   }
} )
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestion but i am using a form to submit the data. I am using Express.js with monk. So if you have a suggestion for same let me know. It will be great. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: @Vijaypandey i'm sorry but can you explain why this is not a solution for you?